# Get Simple List Item Single Choice - Get Selected Item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So, this might be a simple question, or I may be doing things totally off here, but here's what I have:

```
public class SetPrefsActivity extends ListActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radiolist);
    ArrayList<Hall> listItems = new ArrayList<Hall>();
    ArrayAdapter<Hall> ar = new ArrayAdapter<Hall>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, listItems);
    setListAdapter(ar);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
    boolean somethingChecked = false;
    int lastChecked;
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
         long arg3) {
           if(somethingChecked){
               ListView lv = (ListView) arg0;
               TextView tv = (TextView) lv.getChildAt(lastChecked);
               CheckedTextView cv = (CheckedTextView) tv;
               cv.setChecked(false);
           }
           ListView lv = (ListView) arg0;
           TextView tv = (TextView) lv.getChildAt(arg2);
           CheckedTextView cv = (CheckedTextView) tv;
           if(!cv.isChecked())
           cv.setChecked(true);
           lastChecked = arg2;
           somethingChecked=true;
       }
    });
    new LoadListTask().execute(); //This loads Items into the List

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savePrefBtn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //IF SOMETHING IS SELECTED,
            //THEN UPDATE SHARED PREFERENCES

            Intent i = new Intent(SetPrefsActivity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    });
}
//other stuff to fill the arrayAdapter
}
```

What I want to do, is:
When someone clicks the button, it gets information from the listview and updates a shared preference according to the radio option that's selected.

What I'm having trouble with is getting the index of the currently selected item. What is the best way to retrieve that information? Am I implementing the single choice list completely wrong?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

`arg2` is the position in your list.

It looks like you are doing some extra (unnecessary) processing.  `arg1` is your row view, and since the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` layout contains only a `CheckedTextView`, you can use that directly without having to look for it.

```
CheckedTextView cv = (CheckedTextView) arg1;
```